# How to call one method after another in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to call `Method2` and then `Method1`. I know there are multiple ways of doing this like `Method1(Method2());`
But I just tried the below code.
In the below scenario `Method2` is not getting called. So I'm just curious to know where this scenario is useful, why C# has provided this mechanism.

```
public  delegate void Action();
public static void Method1(Action action)
{

}

static void Main()
{
    Method1(Method2);
    return;
}

public static void Method2()
{ 

}
```

Comment: Method2 is not called because you do not invoke `action` in Method1

Comment: As an aside you won´t need your own delegate for `Action`, it comes with .NET 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You should *invoke* `action` within `Method1`:

```
...
public static void Method1(Action action)
{
    // do not forget to validate input for public methods
    if (null == action)  
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    action(); // you should invoke action
}
```

Comment: Then Why do I need to paas Action as parameter in Method1, I can directly call Method2 in Method1

Comment: @Vivek: sure, you can call Method2 directly; I've just corrected your code. Your may want to pass a *lambda* as an action. `e.g. () => a == b ? Method2() : Method3()`